# android - button is making the page background change to gray

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

**Solved**

I have a scroll view that has a Constraint Layout layout inside of it. I Have a button that is constraint to the bottom of the table but it seems to change the background below the table to gray. all other widgets that I have added do not have the same problem.

[Screenshot of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6B3o.png)

I removed the inner code of the table as its not need

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/gaapic" />


        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/homecard"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:elevation="5dp"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
            app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.8"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView3">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                    android:padding="12dp"
                    android:text="@string/recent_news"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvhomePageDate"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="9"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/publish_date"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                    android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.5"
                    android:padding="12dp"
                    android:text="@string/in_news"
                    android:textSize="13sp" />


            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:elevation="90dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/homecard">

            <!-- Table Heading -->
            <TableRow android:background="@color/teal_200">

               

          

        </TableLayout>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTimeCheck"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.092"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tableLayout"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.589" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Live"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tableLayout"/>




    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following to either your `ScrollView` or `ConstraintLayout`:

```
android:background="@android:color/white"
```

Comment: I have the background already set to white, its just that part of the page is gray.

Comment: I don't see where you've set it to white. However, one other thing you can try is to put the button inside of another layout (i.e. Framelayout/Linearlayout) with a white background, then have width=parent and height=wrap_content.

Comment: still gray. It seem to be what every I add after the table the space in-between the table and the new widget is gray

Comment: If you can share your code on GitHub I can pull it down and look into it more for you. My initial thought is still that the Activity/Fragment background's default color is grey, which is why I was trying to edit the parent layouts to be white.

Comment: I solved my problem, I got the idea to put the table in a new layout from you but I cant upvote a comment so thank you. @Shn_Android_Dev

Answer (score 1):

Solved:

I solved my problem by putting the table inside of another Constraint Layout. I don't know if that is best practice but it works for now. Thank you @Shn_Android_Dev

Answer (score 0):

Have you tryed to add .setBackgroundDrawable(null) to you button inside your class?

Example:

```
yourButton.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
```